# Docker accessing path outside build context for COPY

Tags: docker

If my project is structured:

```
docker:
  ==> Dockerfile_1
source_code
```

In Dockerfile1 I have:

```
COPY //source_code
```

How can I add the source_code folder to my dockerfile. I keep getting a message saying that:

```
COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../source_code ()
```

Comment: Can you fix your project structure? It's not clear what the actual structure is (what is `//`?). True being at the level of `source_code` and then run `docker build --file docker/Dockerfile_1`.

Comment: // means I am trying to access a path outside my build context. Just edited as it was in the wrong place

Comment: I don't know `docker`, but the normal way of saying *"fileX from the dirrectory above"* is `../fileX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use paths outside the build context - this is done intentionally such that your container should be fully specified by the files in that directory.

What you usually want to do is simply have the Dockerfile live with the source code - there's rarely a reason to need it far from it.

Another possibility is being in the directory of your source code and using `docker build -f /path/to/Dockerfile`. This would be quite bothersome to use, and in my opinion, I can't see any way this would be justifiable over just placing the Dockerfile in your project root.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense

Comment: `I can't see any way this would be justifiable over just placing the Dockerfile in your project root.` I can - there is a possibility you might need to have more than one Dockerfile for the same project, for instance to create containers with different base OS or for different architectures. Most commonly people have one for lighweight Alpine builds and one for full size Debian, Ubuntu or CentOS-based builds.

Comment: Good point. I'd still put that inside the project's tree though, not outside it, which was the case I was trying to address (bud didn't word well enough)